# show button being pressed when keyboard key is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

well i'm new to c# and i'm using Visual studio 2012.
i'm trying to make a checkbox with the appearance of a button. 
when a keyboard key is pressed i would like for it to show the same way when the mouse clicks a button. If i hit the A key the button/checkbox is pressed down and if A key is hit again the button/checkbox is raised up.

i got this to work with just the button1 but i can't get it to show the pressing of the button by using this code

```
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.D1:
                    // Simulate clicks on button1
                    ShowPictureButton.PerformClick();
                    break;



                default:
                    break;
            }
```

i figured i can use a checkbox so it will stay down when pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying that you are using a `Checkbox` with it's `Appearance` Property set to Button you could do something like this

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.D1:
        // Simulate clicks on CheckBox's
        ShowPictureButton.Checked = !ShowPictureButton.Checked;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first set `KeyPreview` in your form properties to true
add events in your form (`keypress` and `mouseclick`) and then write your code, like this:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            checkBox2.Checked = !checkBox2.Checked;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Visible = !checkBox1.Visible;
    }
```